# Calculating 3D points corrds from 2D image

Tags: 3d, coordinate-systems

The current scenario I have is that I have an image of a rectangular board from an angle and I need to calculate the 4 coordinates of the 4 corners of the rectangle. Currently I have gone through the process and got this information:

[image: Diagram showing the 2D image - MS-Paint for the win!]

Point A: (0,0,0) - acting as origin
Point B: (0-x, 0, 0)
Point C: (0-x, l, d)
Point D: (0, l, d)

It is already known that the two x sides are parallel and are of equal length, which is the same for the tow y sides.

Also I apologise for my lack of terminology, this type of math is all new to me :)

Comment: That would depend on which type of perspective you are using (I'm guessing "a rectangular board from an angle " means that) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_projection

Comment: The image the of the board is taken from an ordinary camera, I dont know what type of perpective that is, Perspective projection I guess...

Comment: I don't think this is really possible with just the information given.  Even if you knew the field of view of the camera, there's no way of knowing whether the board is a small object up close, or a larger object further away.  This is why the kinect has 2 cameras, and we have 2 eyes, etc. You might be able to find the position of each corner as some function of the distance of the camera to the origin, maybe, but that information probably doesn't exist does it

Comment: What I mean by that is, imagine a camera with a 45 degree field of view, aiming at this board, from any angle, even straight on.  Suppose the board is big enough so that it fills 80% of the image width from 20 feet away.  A board of twice the size would also fill the exact same 80%, from 40 ft away, yet the coordinates of their corners would be much different. This is also why many illusions are possible from individual images of things

Comment: I see your point, the scale of the coordinates does not matter which is why I presumed point A is the origin. If it is not possible to get an exact number then is it possible to get an estimate?

Comment: @Nicholas Well since you know the sides are all parallel, it might be possible to calculate the angle it is rotated at based on the line edges. But in all reality, the image might not have enough resolution for that.  The camera would probably have to have been fairly close to have a noticeable difference in line angle across 2 parallel sides. And yes you could get an estimate, a function that gives side lengths based on the distance the origin (point A) is from the camera, and then just best guess how far away the board is in the picture. All comes down to your distance estimate though.

Comment: Here's a picture of what I'm trying to explain. I made this quickly in some random 3D applet I found.  http://i306.photobucket.com/albums/nn255/Krb686/angles.png

In each picture, look at the difference in angle of each side pointed at by the white arrows.  You know each side is actually parallel because it's a cube, but the difference in angle between the two can give information about the rotation. In pic 1 (top left), the camera is exactly in the middle of the cube, notice how the left and right lines are perfectly straight up and down, and the middle front line covers the middle back line.

Comment: In pic 2 (top right), the camera is rotated looking exactly straight down on that side, since the top line covers the bottom line.  In picture 3, (bottom left), you can start to see an angular difference, the camera is rotated somewhere between the middle and the top. In picture 4 (bottom right), the angular difference is most pronounced, as the camera faces straight on to the top line line so it's flat, and the bottom line has an extreme angular difference.

Comment: As far as an estimation goes, here's a sample. http://i306.photobucket.com/albums/nn255/Krb686/sample_triangle.png

You must know the FOV of the camera, the outer black lines. The distance you estimate to the origin is line 3, and the plane that lies in is the red line. The board is the blue line, and appears on the image between the two brown lines.  You can easily find angle 1, the percentage over the left brown line lies from the center * 1/2 the FOV.  Angle 2 you find from the rotation method above, and line 3 you estimate.  So you know 3 details of the triangle and can find the other 3.

Comment: Actually, I think I made that more complex than it needs to be.  For the angle method 2 comments up, notice how in the top left picture the 2 sides pointed at make a 30-60-90 triangle with an imaginary flat line at 45 degree cube rotation.  At 0 degrees cube rotation, the lines would be flat, and at 90, the lines would obviously be straight up and down. So the rotation could be figured from that.